# Nested if in while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested-if

I am having some trouble getting my `while` loop to reiterate when executed. The if statements work as expected but the char value returned from the scanner isn't getting to my while loop. Anyone know what I did wrong or a better solution to my program?

```
package classWork;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        double celsius, fahrenheit, inches, centimeters;
        char doAgain = 'y';

        while (doAgain == 'y' || doAgain == 'Y')
        {

        System.out.print(" Main Menu \n 1. Celsius to Fahrenheit \n 2. Inches to Centimeters \n"
                + "Please select either 1 or 2 \nThen press enter to continue");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("This program will convert a celsius value into a fahrenheit one. \n");

            System.out.println("Please enter the tempature for conversion: ");
            celsius = input.nextInt();

            fahrenheit = 1.8 * celsius + 32.0;

            System.out.println(celsius + " degree(s) in celcius" + " is " + fahrenheit + 
                    " in fahrenheit. \n");

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?\n: " +
                       "enter a \'y \' for another round\n " +
                      " enter a\'n\'   to end the program\n");

            doAgain = input.next().charAt(0);

            input.close();
            return;
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("This program will convert inches to centimeters. \n");


            System.out.println("Please enter the length for conversion: ");
            inches = input.nextInt();

            centimeters = 2.54 * inches;

            System.out.println(inches + " inches is " + centimeters + " centimeters. \n");

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?\n: " +
                       "enter a \'y \' for another round\n " +
                      " enter a\'n\'   to end the program\n");

            doAgain = input.next().charAt(0);

            input.close();
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please restart and try again");
            input.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `return` after asking the user if they want to continue. That will exit the method (and the loop, obviously).

Comment: If you want to repeat you should not have a `return` at the end of your `if` statement blocks

Comment: Now I feel silly because the answer was rather obvious, but hey sometimes that's the way it goes. Thanks a bunch to all who answered it really did help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually 3 issues in your program

#### 1. Don't call `return` to keep iterating

At the end of the 2 `if` blocks you call `return` which makes your application exit from the `main` method so exit from your application that is actually your current issue.

So simply remove them or use `continue` instead.

#### 2. Don't call `close` to keep reading

At the end of the 2 `if` blocks you call `input.close()` which closes the scanner so you won't be able to read anything later without getting a `IllegalStateException`.

So simply remove them.

#### 3. The second `if` should be an `else if`

your code should be:

```
if (choice == 1)
{
    ...
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Because otherwise if your first choice is `1` then you type `y` to iterate your application will go inside the `else` since `choice != 2` which will `close` the scanner as it is wrongly considered as a non valid option.

Comment: Thank you, that was spot on and now so is my program!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the return , it finishes the execution of your main thread